# How to show order delivery date and gift message in success page in magento2.1.7

Tags: magento-2.1.7

I want to show order delivery date and gift message in success page in magento2.1.7 as per my clients requirements.

Comment: https://marketplace.magento.com/navin-module-orderdetails.html

Comment: This will help you out

Comment: Let me know if you stuck anywhere

Comment: Sure, i wil update u

Comment: Check out my answer

Comment: Hello Amy, Have you tried the solution ?

Comment: If any solution works for you then please mark as accepted, which can help future readers.

Comment: Hi, i hv tried the solution but i want the gift message entered by the customer to be shown on success page..sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0):

**[Order Details On Success Page](https://marketplace.magento.com/navin-module-orderdetails.html)**

Customers will be able to check the order details such as billing & shipping address, payment details and brief product details on the order success page. Also, your customers can be greeted with a custom “Thank You” message with a button to Continue Shopping for more products.

- Set custom Thank You message.
- Display shipping and payment information of the order.
- Allow buyers to Continue Shopping from the success page.

> The following information is displayed on the order success page:

- Order number.
- Order status.
- Date of placing the order.
- Shipping address.
- Shipping method.
- Billing address.
- Payment method.